# Object released within block

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm pretty sure I know what is happening, however I want to know if there is a nice way of stopping it from happening.

Basically, I have a class method which looks something up from the core data store, and if nothing exists attempts to fetch it from a web server. The core data lookup and request are performed in the managed object contexts `performBlock` method.

I have the following block of code:

```
[context performBlock:^{
    __block NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:asc selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                 managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:keyPath
                                                                                            cacheName:nil];

    [controller performFetch:&error];

    if (!controller.fetchedObjects || controller.fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
        // Nothing found or an error, query the server instead
                NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kMP_BASE_API_URL, [self baseURL]];
        MPRequest *objRequest = [MPRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [objRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
        [MPUser signRequest:objRequest];

        [objRequest submit:^(MPResponse *resp, NSError *err) {
            if (err) {
                block(nil, err);
            } else {
                NSArray *objects = [self createListWithResponse:resp];
                         objects = [MPModel saveAllLocally:objects forEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
                [controller performFetch:&error];
                block(controller, nil);
            }

        }];
    } else {
        // Great, we found something :)
        block (controller, nil);
    }
}];
```

What is happening, is that the MPRequest object is created, and fired, however the submit method triggers an asynchronous request and thus returns almost instantly. I assume ARC is then releasing the MPRequest object. When the request is performed, the internal request object's delegate no longer exists, as ARC has released it (the MPRequest object is the delegate for the internal request it has). Because of this, the block that the submit method is provided with isn't called.

Is there any way I can prevent ARC for doing this without making the request synchronous?

**Edit**

The `submit` method of `MPRequest` looks like this

```
_completionBlock = block;
   _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[self prepareRequest];

[self prepareRequestHeaders];
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_urlRequest
                                              delegate:self];
[self requestStarted];
```

Comment: What is `MPRequest`? Any sort of asynchronous networking class like this should be able to keep itself alive while it has an outstanding request in flight, just like `NSURLRequest*` does.

Comment: You should also be aware that, since `-submit:` is asynchronous, when the completion block is called, you've already left the context's block. You really should be submitting this outside of the context, and running another `[context performBlock:]` inside of your completion block.

Comment: I don't mind the completion block running outside of the managed objects context. The completion block is executed on the main thread anyway. How do I get MPRequest to keep itself alive? The request itself is still being executed, just the MPRequest itself has been released and therefore never informed of any progress of the actual request.

Comment: Well, you could simply retain yourself when starting the `NSURLConnection*`, and release yourself when you're told that the connection failed or succeeded (e.g. immediately after calling your completion block). Under ARC you can do this with `CFRetain((__bridge CFTypeRef)self)` or `CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)self)`. There are some other ways, but this is the simplest.

Comment: I'd thought of a self retain (although didn't know how with ARC) but everywhere I've read suggests it's a bad approach as it breaks the idea of object ownership??

Comment: It is typically a bad idea, but in this case you're asking for the object to go off and do network activity by itself, and call a completion block when it's done. This is one of the very few exceptions to the idea that objects should never keep themselves alive.

Comment: If it helps, you can think of it as the run loop keeping you alive. That's actually how `NSURLConnection` works, but in your case, you're not being retained by the runloop directly, just conceptually.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it was a terrible idea given I'd be retaining and then releasing as well. It's not gonna cause a leak or anything, and in an async situation like this I can't see any other way around it.

Comment: hmm still doesn't seem to be working? :(

Comment: Now I'm really confused. According to instruments, the object is still alive, and it has in fact retained itself, however the NSURLRequest is not informing it that anything has happened. Any ideas on this? The connection is also still alive in memory according to instruments

Comment: Ahhh turns out it was because the NSURLConnection needed running in the main thread to start. Got that changed and it's fine. If you make an actual Answer @KevinBallard I'll accept it as the retaining self thing has worked with it as well :)

Comment: Yeah, the `NSURLConnection` will schedule itself on the current thread's runloop. If you're in a background dispatch queue, there is no runloop (or rather, the automatically-created one is never actually run), so it won't work. But scheduling it against the main runloop will work.

Comment: Ok, I've reproduced what I said here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MPRequest` object needs to keep itself alive while the connection is running. The simplest way to do this is probably to retain itself when the connection is started, and then release itself after it calls the completion block. Under ARC, the simplest way to do this is

```
CFRetain((__bridge CFTypeRef)self);
```

and

```
CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)self);
```

Conceptually, the run loop keeps the request alive. This is how `NSURLConnection` operates. But since `MPRequest` isn't actually attached to the run loop, it's just a wrapper around `NSURLConnection`, you need to do some work to keep it alive for the same period of time.

Also note that the `NSURLConnection` needs to be added to the appropriate runloop. The convenience method will add it to the current thread's runloop, but if you're in a background queue, that's not going to work. You can use something like

```
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:NO];
[_connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score -1):

set this MPRequest outside of the `context performBlock:^{...}` like so:

```
__strong MPRequest = // allocate or set the MPRequest.
[context performBlock:^{...}
```

Now once the `performBlock` is finished, the MPRequest will not have been released, and still be set to whatever variable you designated it to in the `__strong` clause.

Comment: Still not working. I guess the method this code belongs to is finishing before the request is as well and is releasing the MPRequest still

Comment: Try logging what the MPRequest is equal to prior to the block finishing. If it is equal to nil, then you haven't set the MPRequest properly within your block.

Comment: Looks good. `2013-01-08 20:45:15.148 ManagePlaces[14805:1cd03] <MPRequest: 0x15bc3970>`

Comment: Try replacing __strong with __block.

Comment: I've got __strong __block. I had to add the __block otherwise the compiler complains

Comment: I have to ask because this isn't making any sense: Are you setting your MPRequest to an variable that is entirely outside of your block, and then logging that variable?

Comment: Nope. Just as you suggested. I've got the MPRequest definition inside the method. Bear in mind that the method is a class method, and not instance, so when it finishes there's not parent object for it to stick around for.

Comment: Oh, okay! I was thinking it was an instance this entire time. I'm not really sure then. A guess would be to somehow try and create an observer within your class, `MPRequest`, and then fire a selector when you have made changes to that object. And then that selector will retain the image that you've selected. Again, just a guess haha.